# CSS keyframes - Scale and translate

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to scale and translate an absolute positioned `div`, but after the scale, the `div` won't move to the exact coordinates I gave it in my keyframe.

[image: Demo gif]

I know it's due to the coordinates of the `div`, which remains the same as when unscaled.

I could just adjust the final coordinates of my keyframe, but is there a smarter way to fix that?

---

Here's my code (vendor prefixes removed voluntarily), and [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/4LYH4/2/).

### HTML

```
<div class="popin willGoToUpperLeft"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.popin{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:200px;
    background:url('//placekitten.com/400/200');
}

.willGoToUpperLeft{
  animation: scaleOut 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards, 
             goToLeftCorner 1s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleOut {
  0% { 
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% { 
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
}
@keyframes goToLeftCorner {
  100% { 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
  }
}
```

Comment: What's happening is the Translate is still using the coordinates from before the scale.

Comment: @MiguelStevens That is what I think too, but instead of adjusting the final coordinates, is there a smarter way to fix it?

Comment: Not an expert on CSS animations.. Looking it up but can't find much info :( What does changing the order do?

Comment: @MiguelStevens The final position remain the same, cause it's scaling from the center of the div! If only there was a way to scale from upper left...

Comment: Lucky you! http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Comment: @MiguelStevens Well, that's a workaround, the effect isn't as awesome as scaled from center, but that will work for now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
```

to keep the original coordinates.

It's a workaround, the effect isn't as awesome as scaled from center, but that will work for now.

If someone has a smart solution to keep scaling from center, I'm interested!

Comment: transform-origin: 50% 50%;